# How to retreive terms associated with a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Let's say I have a custom post type (e.g. `product`) and a custom taxonomy (e.g. `prod_cat`).
What I need to do is to get all my custom taxonomy terms associated with an object of my custom post type.
Here is how I do it inside the loop.

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(),'prod_cat', array('fields'=>'slugs'));
```

But it's not working. It returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the function definition](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms), `wp_get_object_terms()` throws an error if it can't find your taxonomy - and returns an empty array if there aren't any taxonomy terms attached to that post. Have you made sure you've assigned a prod_cat to the custom post you're looking at?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I have.

Answer (score 0):

This may help: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

Have you tried something like this:

```
foreach ( get_terms( 'prod_cat' ) as $term ) {
    // Insert some code here
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying?